Write reusable pointer type casting logic in a function or macro
Here is the context of my question. I have this code :
typedef enum DType { float32 } DType;

typedef struct Array {
    void *data;
    DType dtype;
    ...
} Array;

The whole idea is to cast the pointer data to the adequate type depending on the value of the field dtype. Although it is possible to just switch on the dtype everytime it is needed, I would like to know if it's possible to have a function / macro encapsulating that logic and usable anywhere needed.
To further illustrate, here is a non-solution I came up with :
void *cast_data_pointer(Array *arr) {
    switch (arr->dtype) {
        case float32:
            return (float *) arr->data;
        default:
            exit(1);
    }
}

Although the type casting logic is correct, it cannot be used because it requires to know in advance which pointer type will be returned :
Array arr = ...; # with dtype float32
void *data_ptr;

data_ptr = cast_data_pointer(&arr); # wrong because data_ptr is still a void pointer

Array arr = ...; # with dtype float32
float *data_ptr;

data_ptr = cast_data_pointer(&arr); # wrong because it required to know in advance that the function will return a float pointer

Having such a function / macro would avoid repetition as well as would be more flexible when I'll add more dtypes to the DType enum in the future.

You can do something like #define CAST_AND_ASSIGN(dest, src)   (dest) = (typeof(dest))(src).. well, assuming your compiler  has the typeof operator (or __typeof__ or other variants)

Note also that any object pointer can be converted to/from a void * without casting.

...and anyway the function type is void*.

Can also use the C11 generics to some limited extent.

Does the type stored in the Array really have to be decided at runtime or do you already know what type it will contain when you compile the program?

You can't do this with a function, since a function can only return one type. So you just have the same problem dealing with the function's return value.

@dbush: Not sure to understand this : « any object pointer can be converted to/from a void * without casting ». If I want to do pointer arithmetics, don’t I have to do an explicit cast before hand ?

@TedLyngmo : since this project is meant to be an underlying library for another one, I would like to keep this flexibility and not make too much assumptions

@Pauuuuuuul If you're not using a temporary, i.e. ((float *)arr->data)[0] then yes.  But you can assign without a cast, i.e. float *f = arr->data; printf("%f\n", f[0]);

You can use float *data_ptr = arr.data; in C (but not C++).  No cast is needed.  However, there is no check that arr.dtype == float32 either.  I suppose you could use float *data_ptr = (assert(arr.dtype == float32), arr.data);.

Maybe my question wasn’t clear enough but I’m not asking how to cast  a pointer per se, but rather how to factorize the logic to cast a void pointer to another type depending on some variable

But you will need to assign the casted result to something? What would it be?

You don't necessarily need to cast (that is, apply a typecast operator), but you do need to convert the void * to a pointer to the appropriate type in order to access the elements of the array to which it points.  That can be done implicitly by assignment in C, among other ways.

Thanks for the tip ! But how would I write a piece of reusable code to perform such assignment, with the adequate type dynamically computed according to the dtype member ?


The whole idea is to cast the pointer data to the adequate type depending on the value of the field dtype.  Although it is possible to just switch on the dtype everytime it is needed, I would like to know if it's possible to have a function / macro encapsulating that logic and usable anywhere needed.

No, not as you seem to mean.
It is not possible to do what you want with a macro, because macros work at compile time, consuming and producing source code.  They know nothing about the values of variables, and that's the basis on which you say you want to make decisions.
You also cannot do it with a function, because you run into the issue described in the question: you need to know the chosen data type in order to interpret the function result, or else work with a function result such as a tagged union that leaves you in the same place you started.
More generally, in C, every expression has a data type that is known at compile time, and which therefore cannot vary according to the runtime value of any variable.  Choosing behavior based on variables' values requires using conditional statements and / or conditional expressions.
I could imagine various kinds of macro tooling with which you could ease generating the kind of conditional code you will need, but details are situation specific.

On the other hand, you might want to consider approaching the problem in a different way.  There are several alternatives to consider, such as:

create type-specific array-wrapper data types and corresponding functions.  You could avoid tedious repetition by preparing one or several macros that generate the needed declarations and definitions. This is more or less a C version of C++ templates.

implement generic behavior by associating appropriate type-specific functions with your data, that know without referencing a variable how properly to interpret the generic data structure as having elements of the appropriate type.  The callback function used by qsort() is the canonical example of such an approach.  I imagine you may need several such functions, in which case this would amount to a vtable.

rely on the client to do conversions. Make the array-management functions type-agnostic by having them work in terms of untyped items of specified size (for example, using memcpy() instead of =).  This, too, is reminiscent of qsort().



Thanks for the answer ! Could you please show me an example or point me to the « macro tooling » you mention ?

Not really, @Pauuuuuuul.  As I already said, details are situation-specific.  They also depend in part on how complex of a macro stack you are prepared to engage (and there's one of the main trade-offs).  I often approach that kind of thing by first writing a concrete example of the code I want to be able to generate, then looking at how best to parameterize it for generation via macro.  In a case like this, I would probably at least consider an approach based on X macros, but that does get a bit involved.

Type-generic programming in modern C isn't about storing type info in a variable and then take a certain execution path in run-time. It can be about calling the relevant callback function based on type, as for example done in this post about OO polymorphism: How do you implement polymorphism in C? But preferably type-generic programming should be determining the type at compile-time and then at compile-time decide which functions that will be called etc. This gives type safety and it eliminates run-time overhead. For this you'll have to use _Generic and/or typeof (C23).
"X-macros" was mentioned in a comment to another answer and they can be used to create a list of supported types. This isn't really recommended practice, since code generation based on X-macros can turn the code quite evil-looking and hard to trouble-shoot. But on the other hand "X-macros" is a well-known design pattern, as opposed to inventing some macro language of our own.
So just for reference, this is how it might look like:
#define SUPPORTED_TYPES(X) \
  X(int,      "%d")        \
  X(double,   "%lf")       \
  X(uint32_t, "%"PRIu32)   \

This is a finite list of all supported types for the type-generic usage. We can add any additional info there related to the type - in this case I used printf conversion specifiers.
We can then generate a function per type by writing a generic macro taking type + format as parameters, then call that macro for every item in the X-macro list:
#define PRINT(type, fmt)                  \
  void print_##type (type val)            \
  {                                       \
    printf(fmt "\n", val);                \
  }
SUPPORTED_TYPES(PRINT)

So this will generate 3 functions print_int, print_double and print_uint32_t, all with the correct parameter type. Link-time optimization will remove any function that isn't actually used by the program, so we don't have to worry about that. (This works very much like C++ templates, just with cruder syntax.)
Picking up the _Generic compile-time expression, we can then write a type-generic macro which calls one of the 3 functions. We have to bake in the _Generic "association list" in another X-macro input, so that it corresponds to our list of supported types:
#define GENERIC_LIST(type, fmt) type: print_##type,

And then make the generic print macro based on this:
#define print(val)                        \
  _Generic((val),                         \
    SUPPORTED_TYPES(GENERIC_LIST)         \
    default: (void)0) (val)

This will boil down to a list of function names called with the passed parameter, which is what the (val) in the end of the macro. Or in case of non-supported types, run into some nonsense code (void)0 (val) which will trip a compiler error.
Full example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define SUPPORTED_TYPES(X) \
  X(int,      "%d")        \
  X(double,   "%lf")       \
  X(uint32_t, "%"PRIu32)   \

#define PRINT(type, fmt)                  \
  void print_##type (type val)            \
  {                                       \
    printf(fmt "\n", val);                \
  }
SUPPORTED_TYPES(PRINT)

#define GENERIC_LIST(type, fmt) type: print_##type,
#define print(val)                        \
  _Generic((val),                         \
    SUPPORTED_TYPES(GENERIC_LIST)         \
    default: (void)0) (val)

int main (void)
{
  int i = 123;
  double d = 3.1415;
  uint32_t u32 = 456;

  print(i);
  print(d);
  print(u32);
  // print(1.0f); // compiler error
}

Output:
123
3.141500
456

